# PHP and Ajax a onclick function

Tags: php, ajax

I have a menu, I want when select item from menu, the content displays, but I can't call ajax function. When I click in item from menu, in address line was appeared only id of selected item:

```
http://localhost:8080/treeview/#2
```

HTML code from a browser:

```
<a onclick="callPage(1)"; href="#1 "> <span style="color:yellow";>item1</span></a>
```

The PHP code, where I form html code:

```
 $out .= '<li id="'.$item['id'].'"> <label for="subfolder2">';
 $out .= '<a onclick="callPage('.$item['id'].')"; href="#'.$item['id'].' "> <span style="color:'.$item['color'].'";>'.$item['title'].'</span></a>';
 $out .= ' </label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder2"/>';
```

AJAX function:

```
// JavaScript Document
function callPage(id)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("pageContent").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php?id="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

A Content file, I was tested, he work well, when I take him in address bar in browser:

```
<?php function __autoload($class){
include_once($class.".php");
}
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];

$db = new oopCrud();
$rty = $db->getById($id);

echo $rty['title'];
echo $rty['color'];
?>
```

Comment: No, when I am clicking menu item in address bar only changes id.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No. It hasn't errors.